# How to make android os suggest a flutter application while trying to open a file with particular extension eg: .torrent

Tags: android, flutter, dart, operating-system

While opening a file in an android device, the os suggests compatible applications based on the extension of the file. (eg: On opening a *.torrent* file, the os automatically suggests the installed torrent clients). Is there a way to make the os suggest an installed **flutter application** when a document of a particular format is opened?

Also, opening the app through a particular file should ***trigger a callback*** in the app to handle relevant events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this doc. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTop"
  android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
  <!-- ... -->
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

android:mimeType [Extensions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/61ae88e/core/java/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.java) list